# Sagepay redirects to Magento empty cart page

Tags: php, magento, opayo

I have setup the ebizmarts plugin with my Magento store, everything works great. The user gets sent to Sagepay, the payment is processed, the user receives Sagepay email. But the redirect goes to the empty cart page instead of the success page.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Please note:
This was working fine, the only thing I have changed and not sure if it is a coincidence is I added a tax rule to the product, and after reading through various forums some say it could may be a (suhosin.get.max_value_length directive problem) so adding tax would this go beyond the max length.

Comment: Have you checked... is redirection url is missing?

Comment: Hi Rajiv, 

I have checked with Sagepay and they said that they don't get sent a URL and you don't have an option to insert one in the ebizmarts plugin or on Sagepay admin.

It has been working fine so I am guessing there is one being sent.Will definitely give another check though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know, I had two tax rules setup and this was causing a database error with duplicate content. Once I deleted one of the rules it worked fine. I hope this helps anyone else suffering with the same problem.

Thanks